# Copy to Clipboard on Button Click Event, the Current URL with prepended and/or appended text in Javascript/jQuery

Tags: jquery, tampermonkey

The goal is to add a button that will copy the page URL and amend text to the front and end of the URL using jQuery. So far, I have:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("click", "#ShareButton", function (e) {
        $("body").append('<input id="copyURL" type="text" value="" />');
        $("#copyURL").val(window.location.href).select();
        document.execCommand("copy");
        $("#copyURL").remove();            
    });
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What is your question, specifically? Please edit your question to include this. This seems to be working as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/v4bfn1j3/

Comment: I know that the script grabs the URL, but would like it to add text to the front and end of the url, so that when someone clicks the button then it copies it to their keyboard and will paste something like (insertedtext)copiedurl(insertedtext)

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**

https://jsfiddle.net/jx7fg5eo/6/

```
    $(() => $('#ShareButton').on("click", () =>
      navigator.clipboard.writeText(
        'prepended text ' + 
        window.location.href + 
        ' appended text'
      )
    ));
```

**NOTE:**

If the **SOLUTION** above does not work in your specific environment, try some of the other solutions in the **EXPLANATION** section below.  Mainly, the arrow functions and event delegation. (Safe Rollback: https://jsfiddle.net/jx7fg5eo/1/)

**EXPLANATION:**

https://jsfiddle.net/jx7fg5eo/

For a quick and dirty fix, just change one line...

This is the line assigning a value to the element with `id=copyURL`, hence the `.val()`.  The argument sent to `.val()` is `window.location.href` (aka the current URL).  So if you want to prepend or append to that URL, you can simply use javascript's string concatenation operator, the `+`, as I have demonstrated below (and in the fiddle linked above).

```
$("#copyURL").val('something' + window.location.href + 'or other').select();
```

However, the logic behind the entire algorithm you are using is not clean or efficient, as the best practice would be using...

[navigator.clipboard.writeText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/writeText)

as per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) ...

> The "clipboard-write" permission of the [Permissions API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions_API), is granted
> automatically to pages when they are in the active tab.

So the final code would be much cleaner (whitespace added for readability)... https://jsfiddle.net/jx7fg5eo/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("click", "#ShareButton", function (e) {
         navigator.clipboard.writeText(
           'prepended text ' + 
           window.location.href + 
           ' appended text');           
    });
});
```

Or a little cleaner using arrow function ... https://jsfiddle.net/jx7fg5eo/2/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("click", "#ShareButton", () => 
      navigator.clipboard.writeText('prepended text ' + 
      window.location.href + ' appended text'
    ));
});
```

and cleaner still, you can use an => function for document.ready as you are only performing one operation.  Haven't tried it with multiple operations, not sure if that would work.... https://jsfiddle.net/jx7fg5eo/4/

```
$(() => $(document).on("click", "#ShareButton", () => 
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(
    'prepended text ' + 
    window.location.href + 
    ' appended text'
  )
));
```

Finally, you are using event delegation on the click event. Event delegation is necessary if you are dynamically creating the `#ShareButton`, or any of it's parent containers, after `DOM (document) ready`.  If the content is not being dynamically generated, you can move the 2nd argument to `.on()` to the preceding selector expression.... https://jsfiddle.net/jx7fg5eo/6/

```
$(() => $('#ShareButton').on("click", () =>
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(
    'prepended text ' + 
    window.location.href + 
    ' appended text'
  )
));
```